# Alternative to g_variant_lookup_value when the key is not an string type

Tags: c, glib

are there any alternative to g_variant_lookup_value when the key is not a string type (i.e. the key is an integer)?

I have a function which takes a "a{ias}" dictionary like a GVariant *. I want to get the arrays of strings related to one key (which is an int value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything already built into glib (though I'm not all that familiar with the GVariant API), but looking at the [g_variant_lookup_value implementation](http://git.gnome.org/browse/glib/tree/glib/gvariant.c?id=f66052fc87caada2552f651e9a21f1daac86b2a1#n1030) it would be trivial to create a modified version in your code which behaves like that.